# how to prevent UPDATE of existing rows/record but allow INSERT using PostgreSQL trigger?

Tags: postgresql, trigger

How do I prevent UPDATE on any record in a given table, but allow INSERT, I already have created a trigger which prevents update but I found that it also prevents INSERT.

**EDIT**
I can INSERT new row/record from the database itself but not from the form for a new record of the application that is connected to this database, after submitting the form, the trigger is being executed.

It's a web application built with Django.

**TRIGGER FUNCTION**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prevent_updte()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
RAISE EXCEPTION 'Data modification not allowed';
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

**TRIGGER**

```
CREATE Trigger prevent_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON purchases_purchase
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE prevent_update();
```

Comment: Something was wrong with the database. I dropped the existing database and created a new database and everything works fine now. thank you, I have updated the question.

Comment: Please do not edit your question if you found a solution. Add an answer and accept that answer. Without an accepted answer the question will remain "unsolved"

Answer (score 7):

You can use [GRANT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) & [REVOKE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-revoke.html) for this purpose:

```
 CREATE TABLE TEST (ID int, NAME text);

 REVOKE ALL ON TABLE TEST FROM CURRENT_USER;

 GRANT INSERT ON TABLE TEST TO CURRENT_USER;
 GRANT SELECT ON TABLE TEST TO CURRENT_USER;
```

```
 INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (1, 'NAME 1'),(2, 'NAME 2');
```

```
UPDATE TEST SET NAME='NAME 3' WHERE ID = 1;
ERROR:  permission denied for table test
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=646de8d4fe610bc79cc29f35525c3e27)*